# Update DataSource from UITextView in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, uitableview

I  have a `UITableView` and each `UITableViewCell` contains an editable `UITextView`.

My data source is a `NSMutableArray` containing `NSMutableDictionary` that holds the text value and some styling keys for the text.

How can I (efficiently) make it so that any changes a user makes to the UITextView are updated in the corresponding datasource `NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather simple way is to utilize the index path of the table, it is NOT the cleanest so it depends on the complexity of your datasource, and if you have multiple tables etc.

What you can do is when the user ends editing the textView or selects another row in tableView, you read the indexPath of the selected row (That requires that the row keeps actually being in the selected state while editing the textView which it should by default). From there you call your update method.

To catch the end of editing you implement

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   NSIndexPath *selectedpath = [myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
   [self myUpdateMethodForIndexPath:selectedpath];
}
```

To catch deselect of the table row and the above doesnt get called, you implement

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self myUpdateMethodForIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Your update method must then read the value of the textView at the corresponding cell at the indexPath and handle this in the datasource. To care for sections of course you need to correctly handle the indexPath, in the example just the row is used (1 section).

```
-(void)myUpdateMethodForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)editPath 
{
 UITableViewCell *editCell = [myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:editPath];
 NSString *newText = editCell.theTextView.text;
 ....
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [myDictArray objectAtIndex:editPath.row];
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must assign a tag to each UITextView, to know exactly which UITextView are you refering.

Then you must implement UITextViewDelegate in your view controller which holds the tableview. Then, make this view controller the delegate of each UITextView. Read here how to implement it: [UITextViewDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html).

Look for the protocol method that better fits your needs (probably – textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:, wich is called each time the text changes in any range.

In the delegate method, you can read the text with UITextView.text property, and assign this value to your data model (the dictionary).

Another possible approach is to use KVO pattern, but it requires more coding and a better understanding both, the pattern and the implementation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Using `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` is not appropriate. It is called before the text changes and its implementation can either prevent the change, make other changes, or allow the pending change to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Make your view controller the delegate of each text view. Listen for appropriate events to get the updated text. Then have the view controller update the data model with the updated text.

If you have custom cells then have the cell be the text view delegate. Then the cell should notify its delegate (the view controller) about the updated text. Of course this requires that your custom cell class define its own delegate protocol and the view controller should make itself the delegate of each cell.

That's as specific as an answer can be for such a vague question.